# VueJs Deployment Problem: Chrome caches old version and not updating app

Tags: javascript, vue.js, version-control, vuetify.js, web-deployment

I'm having a problem with deploying my project.
It's `VueJs` project, a web app, build on **Metronic** template with **Vuetify** components.
When I publish, I use visual studio code with `npm run build` and upload the **dist** folder to my server.
I have a version-check problem.
Some of my clients cannot get the latest version, without hard reloading. `ctrl-shift-r` they are using chrome and when incognito mode is on everything is perfect. But normal mode brings a very old version of the app.
I need a solution on the code or server-side, thank you for your help

Comment: Probably no way to do in the code, you might need to update the build script somehow it generates different version of the file, so after build, you can rename the file or try adding version every time. Then upload the folder, this is how generally FE apps avoid file caching.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem and I forgot to post my answer. My problem was because of the PWA package I installed and implemented in the beginning of the project.

When I try to remove PWA from my project, what I did was commenting the code blocks but not removing dependency from my packacge.json.(mistake) So, I was thinkin, *"Since I'm not calling any of the PWA functions or initialize it, it should've been removed."
**yeah, not.**
It was still there, caching stuff.
So I removed (uninstalled) the dependency from my packacge.json, and even after that, people who did installed PWA before and **"not uninstalled properly"** was still using cache! (yeah, you have to  click uninstall and also check remove files option)
so I had to, manually uninstalled my PWA app from their chrome (thankfully it was only few) and problem solved.